# Uploading images in Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

I'm loading multiple images and sometimes it works fine and another hangs, other times it doesn't take certain images and redirects me to page 404. I would like if you can give me a hand. I appreciate very much any intention.

I am using Livewire as follows:

```
<input wire:model="imagenes" type="file" name="imagenes" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```

Once the images are selected, it goes through the validator:

```
$this->validate([
    'imagenes.*' => 'image|max:2048',
]);
```

And to save the images I am using the following methodology

```
foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {
         $imgUrl = $pathGaleria->store('imagenesPropiedades');

         $img = imgPropiedades::create([
               'url' => $imgUrl,
               'property_id' => $this->propiedadId
         ]);
}
```

On the filesystem:

```
'imagenesPropiedades' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

I get this error in console

[image]

Can you give me a suggestion to improve this load please.

Comment: I suggest you do some debugging to figure out what conditions result in an error.

Comment: Do you have the `use WithFileUploads;` trait?

Comment: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads

Comment: @miken32 Perform a debugging and the error is varied, there are times that certain images do not take them and give an error. I can't quite detect why.

Comment: @Quirel If i use it.

Comment: Did you specify enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute on a form tag?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that since I use livewire in real time, I had not contemplated the enctype = "multipart / form-data" tag, and I also had to expand the max_upload server spaces. Thanks a lot